# Method alias with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I assume this is the easiest way to implement a method alias with TS:

```
export class Foo {

 bar(){

 }

 aliasOfBar(){
   return this.bar.apply(this, arguments);
 }

}
```

but I am simply wondering if there is another way we can define an alias with TS (or JS). Perhaps ideally without an extra function call.

If I do this, for example:

```
let mySharedFn = function () {

};

export class Foo {
  public bar = mySharedFn
  public aliasBar = mySharedFn
}
```

it transpiles to this:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var mySharedFn = function () {
};
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
        this.bar = mySharedFn;
        this.aliasBar = mySharedFn;
    }
    return Foo;
}());
exports.Foo = Foo;
```

I'd like to avoid those extra calls that come with using the constructor to create the methods, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add the alias method to the class using an interface and the prototype, like this:

```ts
class Person {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
    greet(greeting: string): string { return `${greeting}, ${this.name}`; }
}

interface Person {
    hi: typeof Person.prototype.greet;
}
Person.prototype.hi = Person.prototype.greet;

const p = new Person("Alice");
console.log(p.greet("Hey"));
console.log(p.hi("Hi"));
```

Comment: so the interface and the class should/must have the same name?

Comment: To add an alias to the class, yes.

Comment: Great! just in case, interfaces are not mandatory for this, for example, in my case I hate writing interfaces and let the compiler do for me. Your trick worked like a charm only modifying the class. Thanks!

Comment: This works. To improve further, I typed the alias as a method `hi(...args: Parameters<typeof Person.prototype.greet>): ReturnType<typeof Person.prototype.greet>;` (minor change in how tooling, e.g. VSCode shows the auto-complete; but might help somebody)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something with bind or with a reference:

```
export class Foo {
    public bar() {}
    public aliasBar = this.bar.bind(this);
    public aliasGreetSecond;
    constructor() {
        this.aliasGreetSecond = this.bar;
    }
}
```

the above will transpile to:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
        this.aliasBar = this.bar.bind(this);
        this.aliasGreetSecond = this.bar;
    }
    Foo.prototype.bar = function () { };
    return Foo;
}());
exports.Foo = Foo;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Test this in TypeScript playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    aliasGreetSecond;

    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
        this.aliasGreetSecond = this.greet;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }

    aliasGreet = this.greet.bind(this);
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");

let button = document.createElement('button');
let button2 = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "With bind";
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(greeter.aliasGreet());
}

 button2.textContent = "With reference";
 button2.onclick = function() {
    alert(greeter.aliasGreetSecond());
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
document.body.appendChild(button2);
```

Which will transpile into:

```
var Greeter = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Greeter(message) {
        this.aliasGreet = this.greet.bind(this);
        this.greeting = message;
        this.aliasGreetSecond = this.greet;
    }
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    };
    return Greeter;
}());
var greeter = new Greeter("world");
var button = document.createElement('button');
var button2 = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "With bind";
button.onclick = function () {
    alert(greeter.aliasGreet());
};
button2.textContent = "With reference";
button2.onclick = function () {
    alert(greeter.aliasGreetSecond());
};
document.body.appendChild(button);
document.body.appendChild(button2);
```

Comment: I am not sure if `this` is defined in that context?

Comment: this seems to work, but I am going to see if anyone has other ideas thanks, will accept it soon if nobody comes up with something better :)

Comment: You could also simply reference the prototype I guess

Comment: Also no need in `bind`. Just `aliasOfBar = this.bar;`